# CALayer sublayerTransform and contentsScale do not play well together

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I've set up some example layers like this. Every layer scales down its sublayers contents by `0.75`.

```
CGColorRef color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128);

m_layer0 = [CATextLayer new];
m_layer0.string = @"0";
m_layer0.frame = frame;
m_layer0.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.75, 0.75, 0.75);
m_layer0.masksToBounds = NO;
m_layer0.foregroundColor = color; 

m_layer1 = [CATextLayer new];
m_layer1.string = @"  1";
m_layer1.frame = frame;
m_layer1.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.75, 0.75, 0.75);
m_layer1.masksToBounds = NO;
m_layer1.foregroundColor = color;

m_layer2 = [CATextLayer new];
m_layer2.string = @"    2";
m_layer2.frame = frame;
m_layer2.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.75, 0.75, 0.75);
m_layer2.masksToBounds = NO;
m_layer2.foregroundColor = color;

[m_layer0 addSublayer:m_layer1];
[m_layer1 addSublayer:m_layer2];

[m_hostView.layer addSublayer:m_layer0];
```

The `hostView` is a subview of an `UIScrollView` and on zoom, I set the appropriate `contentsScale` factor on its sublayers to get a crisp look.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    m_layer0.contentsScale = scale;
    m_layer1.contentsScale = scale;
    m_layer2.contentsScale = scale;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This produces following output image when zoomed in. [image]

Why is the first sublayer rendered correctly but the sublayer of that all blurry?

Comment: I found a [hint](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/Jun/msg01020.html) on the cocoa-dev mailing list. Apparently a scale transform does not re-render the content on scale. This seems to have something to do with video card memory.

Comment: This seems not be a problem of `CATextLayer` directly, but occurs also when text is draw in a `CALayer`'s `-drawInContext:`. Any suggestions?

Comment: When rendering with `-drawInContext:` you need to call `-setNeedsDisplay` on each layer after it's been scaled by the scroll view. I'm not sure about `CATextLayer`'s behavior though.

Comment: Doesn't work, that's what I tried at first actually.

Comment: Without knowing any more about your code it's hard to tell what's going wrong. Only stabs in the dark seem likely to work at this point. Did you confirm that your scroll view's delegate is properly set up and `-scrollViewDidEndZooming...` is actually getting called by checking in the debugger? Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Nevermind, filed a TSI with Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a TSI on this one. Here is the solution:

The problem is that I'm scaling the Z axis as well as the X and Y axes, which causes the layer to take a more complex rendering path. So `CATransform3DMakeScale(0.75, 0.75, 1.0)` would be the 'correct' way to do it.

If you truly want to enable z-depth in sublayer transforms, you would set the `m34` value such as:

```
CATransform3D thisIsHowYouEnable3DForALayer = CATransform3DIdentity; 
thisIsHowYouEnable3DForALayer.m34 = -1.0/kSomeCameraDistanceValue;
parentView.layer.sublayerTransform = thisIsHowYouEnable3DForALayer;
```